# Repeat or while loop with map function in a simulation in r

Tags: r, dictionary, tidyverse, repeat, purrr

Below is my data where columns group, score and prob represent treatment groups, scores outcome and probability of occurrence of the score outcome

```
data1 <- tibble(group = rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 5),
       score = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
       prob = c(.08, .8, .1, .02, 0, 0, 0, .4, .4, .2)) 

data1
```

I want to use this data and simulate the scores `R` times so I expand as follows

```
R <- 1:10 # number of simulations

data2 <- data1 %>%
  nest(data = c(score, prob)) %>%
  unnest_wider(col = data) %>%
  mutate(size = 15) 

data3 <- data2 %>%
  group_by(group, score, prob, size) %>%
  tidyr::expand(iter = R) %>%
  ungroup 

data3
```

My function to simulate the data is as follows  where I use multinomial distribution

```
sim_data <- function(dt, n, size, prob){
  d1 <- dt %>%
    mutate(sim_score = pmap(list(n    = 1,
                                 size = size,
                                 prob = prob),
                            rmultinom)) %>%
    select(-prob) %>%
    unnest(cols = c(sim_score, score))
  
  # create real scores from counts above
  d2 <- d1 %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(outcome = map(score, rep, times = sim_score)) %>%
    unnest(cols = outcome) %>%
    select(size, contains('iter'), group, outcome) %>%
    nest(data = c(group, outcome))
  
  return(d2)
}

data4 <- sim_data(data3, n, size, prob)
data4
```

This works fine however I want to omit those instances where each group has less than or equal to 2 unique scores. In this case, I modify my function `sim_data` to do the check as follows using `repeat` so as to ignore cases that do not meet the above mentioned requirement

```
 sim_check <- function(my_data, n, size, prob){
  
  repeat{
    # simulate data
    dt = sim_data(my_data, n, size, prob)
    
    # check requirement
    check <- dt %>%
      select(data) %>%
      unnest(cols = c(data)) %>%
      group_by(group) %>%
      distinct(outcome) %>%
      mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
      summarise(n = n()) %>%
      distinct(n) %>%
      pull(n)
    
    if(all(check > 2)) break
  }
  return(dt)
}

data5 <- sim_check(data3, n, size, prob)
```

This however does not do the checking as I see observations with 2 unique scores.

I can achieve my objective with a for loop as follows but I want to avoid the for loop. Can someone point out where I'm doing wrong

```
out <- list()

for(i in 1:10){
  data6 <- sim_check(data2, n, size, prob)
  out[[i]]  <- data6 %>%
    pull(data) 
}
```

@Ronak thanks for the observation. I just corrected it

Comment: I didn't quite understand the question but a simple translation of your `for` loop would be `map(1:10, ~sim_check(data2, n, size, prob) %>% pull(data))`. Do you need that?